# Cramer Rao bound for relative estimation

Tags: it.information-theory, lower-bounds, signal-analysis, estimation-theory

I have an observed vector ${\bf y}$ from which I would like to estimate a parameter vector ${\bf c}$ (denote the estimate $\hat{{\bf c}}$).

A feature of our estimation problem is that the involved likelihood is invariant to rotations in the parameter vector, i.e.,
$$p({\bf y}|\exp(i\beta){\bf c})=p({\bf y}|{\bf c}),$$

which leads to the same parameter estimate up to a phase rotation.

Therefore, I only care about estimation errors up to a common complex rotation. To deal with this, I measure the error as follows
$$\delta=\min_{\beta} \|\exp(i\beta)\hat{{\bf c}}-{\bf c}\|^2.$$

Is there a concept of a Cramer-Rao bound on $\delta$ in this case?